# Check if there is row with the same data in two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I got table with 3 columns (Primary)id, type, name. I am inserting data into this table, and I need to prevent multiple rows with the same type and name. How can I check this and insert in one query?

I was trying

```
IF ((select id from models where type = 1 and name = 'test') is null)
THEN insert into models(type, name) values(1, 'test');
END IF;
```

but it is not working and I have no idea why( 0 experience with conditions in mysql) - it is giving me syntax error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF ((select id from models where type = 1 and name = 'test') is null)
THEN inse' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is needed in general (not only for this Insert), you should add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `(type, name)` combination:

```
ALTER TABLE models
  ADD UNIQUE KEY type_name_U (type, name) ;
```

Then you can simply add rows and if the combination exists in the table, the Insert will fail:

```
INSERT INTO  models(type, name)
  VALUES (1, 'test') ;
```

---

For one-time check only, try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO  models(type, name)
  SELECT 1, 'test'
  FROM dual
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
          FROM models
          WHERE type = 1 
            AND name = 'test'
        )
```

Comment: Did not know you can put unique index on multiple columns, thank you, solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Add unique key (type, name), and do [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)s with IGNORE clause, it will help you to avoid exeptions.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
INSERT INTO models
SELECT
    s.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        1 AS type,
        'test' AS name
) AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN models x
    ON x.type = s.type
    AND x.name = s.name
WHERE x.type IS NULL
```

Comment: Not `SELECT *` but: `SELECT s.*`